# Multiple Composite Repositories with JDBC + Native

Tags: jdbc, configuration, server, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

How to create a composite repositories with 'native'+'jdbc'?

I tried different configurations, but the priority is always given to `jdbc`.
Even when some config is only available in 'native' repository, the flow is always retrieved from `jdbc`.
From the following configuration, what is expected is to retrieve first any existing configuration from file system. But only jdbc is considered.

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native,jdbc
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:/data

spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.order=2
spring.cloud.config.server.native.order=1

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/props_db
spring.datasource.username=omc
spring.datasource.password=omc
```

Comment: _"I tried different configurations"_ Please include details on those attempts, what you expected and what actually happened.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb: I'm using spring cloud Finchley.M8.